# when and why we use xml file in asp.net. I know, it is used for dynamic programming but exactly why we need to save data in xml instead of database?

Tags: asp.net, xml

when and why we use xml file in asp.net. I know, it is used for dynamic programming but exactly why we need to save data in xml instead of database/

Comment: Please clarify what you are talking about. XML is a good way to store configuration and settings but it's not a good substitute for a database.

Comment: actually, I am new in asp.net and I am using xml in asp.net as web.config file in which I am writing connectionstring and many settings but in my interview interviewer asked me this is one use of xml file and tell me any other use of xml files in asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is a good way to store configuration and settings and for communication but it's not a good substitute for a database. **You should not use an XML file instead of storing data in a database.**

Here are some uses of XML in ASP.NET that come to my mind.

- Configuration such as `.config` files
- Settings (for example, `.settings` files)
- When you communicate with external web services, XML is a popular choice (see `SOAP`)
- Due to the relative ease one can work with XML files in .NET many people base custom solutions on the XML format, our company uses it for content type definitions (CTD) and as an export format

Some ways in which you can manipulate XML files

- [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (since .NET 1.0)
- [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (also known as LINQ to XML, added in .NET 3.5)